# AngularJS custom window while changing page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onbeforeunload

I want to do a custom modal asking if user wants to save changes before leaving a page, using ui.bootstrap.

I'm not using angular route configuration (so i guess i can't use '$locationChangeStart'or '$routeChangeStart').

I can't use window.onbeforeunload as you can't custom the popup window ( apart maybe from the messages displayed ).

Any idea ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a directive, something similar to this:

```
app.directive('a', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, el) {
            $(el).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                alert('Do your modal stuff here');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mmansion/LXAt7/) is a working example. You can pass the href to the modal, and if they click through, you can use the href to redirect the page to their final destination.

Comment: I'm not sure you saved your jsfiddle, or maybe you mistook in copy/paste of the link.
I did a plunker with your solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/WWrkIMpTpEPpO1QIgZ7h?p=preview

But in what you said, you prevent the change of location in any case. So i used the even.target to redirect in case we need, not sure it's a good solution ?

Comment: Ok so finally, i added an event broadcasted on the click, and caught the  event to redirect if needed. Thank you.